# C# Functional Programming Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

I don't understand why the following code has the output 230. Please help.
The code and output are posted below. You can edit the below code with linqpad, or you can read the code below.

```
void Main() {
    int ten = 10;
    int twenty = 20;
    int thirty = 30;

    int temp = 10.Where(t => 20); // X.Where(10,20);
    int result0 = temp.Select(t => 30);  
    result0.Dump("result0");

    int result1 = 
        from c in ten 
        where twenty 
        select thirty;    

    result1.Dump("result1");

    int result2 = 
        ten.Where(t => twenty).Select(t => thirty);

    result2.Dump("result2");
}

static class X {
    public static int Where(this int c, Func<int, int> f) {
        return c * f(0); 
    }
    public static int Select(this int c, Func<int, int> f) {
        return c + f(0); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
result0
230 

result1
230 

result2
230
```

Comment: This code is physically hurting my eyes. What are you even trying to achieve?

Comment: In which language does this compile?

Comment: Hint: `t => 20` is a function that always returns 20. It totally ignores its parameter.

Comment: I think you have absolutely no idea what you are doing there.

Comment: It *doesn't compile*, at least `10.Where(t => 20);`

Comment: This compiles just fine (assuming the Dump(...) extension method exists) http://ideone.com/OhdP22

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

The static method `Where` returns `c * f(0)`
The static method `Select` returns `c + f(0)`

The line `int temp = 10.Where(t => 20);` will result in `10 * 20 = 200`
The line `int result0 = temp.Select(t => 30);` will result in `200 + 30 = 230`

The additonal code just performs the same calculation using differing syntax.
The result is therefore a predicatable `230`

If you are wondering why the zero in `f(0)` does not result in a zero.
The lambda `t => 20` returns 20 regardless of `t`
If you want the value returned, you need to change it to `t => t`

in which case the zero will be returned.